# How can I modify elements inside vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, element

I'm trying to modify the elements inside a vector. After I change a certain block in an array and display it again, it won't show the new values but instead, retain the previous output. Am I doing it wrong?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This displays the array/maze
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void displayMaze( vector< vector<char> > &maze ) {
    for( int i = 0; i < ROW; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < COL; j++ ) {
            cout << "[" << maze[ i ][ j ] << "] ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is where I change a certain element
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void updateMouse( vector< vector<char> > maze, const int &mouse_row, const int &mouse_col ) {
    for( int row = 0; row < ROW; row++ ){
        for( int col = 0; col < COL; col++ ) {
            if( ( row == mouse_row ) && ( col == mouse_col ) ) {
                maze[ row ][ col ] = 'M';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `updateMouse` method you pass a vector by copy, not a reference. Try to correct it like in the first method. Are you sure that you enter inside the if statement?

Comment: [Yeah I got through](http://i60.tinypic.com/2exmveu.png)
but
[the display is wrong](http://i59.tinypic.com/2rqobk3.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`updateMouse` takes the `maze` argument *by value*. Any changes it makes to the `vector` are made to the local copy within the function, which will be destroyed when the function exits. Change the function so that it takes the `maze` argument *by reference*.

```
void updateMouse( vector<vector<char>>& maze, const int &mouse_row, const int &mouse_col ) {
//                                   ^^^
```

---

The `updateMouse` function can also be simplified to

```
void updateMouse( vector<vector<char>>& maze, int mouse_row, int mouse_col ) {
    if(mouse_row < maze.size()) {
        if(mouse_col < maze[mouse_row].size()) {
            maze[mouse_row][mouse_col] = 'M';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know it will be destroyed when the function exits @_@ I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the explanation and thanks for simplifying! :D I can see the changes in the display now :D

All it needed was referencing, thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing your `vector` as a reference (or pointer):

```
void updateMouse( vector< vector<char> > & maze, const int &mouse_row, const int &mouse_col ) {
```

Otherwise what you do is you change the copy of the maze